# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. in angular app when running vs code launch.config

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have been using a launch.config file in my angular project to debug it right in vs code. Today I started to refactor the folder structure of my project and at some point that error popped up and I don't know how to fix it. I have already searched on Google and tried a bunch of things but nothing worked. Not even going back to any previous commit fixed the problem.
However, the weirdest thing for me is that when I just run `ng serve` the app works totally fine.

I know I could just leave it at this because my app still works. However, I really don't want to go back to debugging my code in Chrome.